# What is the exact configuration (e.g. MIMO configuration) of the 802.11ac of the Pi Model B?

Tags: wireless

The specs for the Pi 4 Model B say dual band 802.11ac but not the degree of MIMO, critical for performance.   What is it.   Is there provision to add external antennae?

Comment: Am interested in the original question too. Plus further sub-questions: 1) Range with built in anntenna(e)? 2) Throughput to USB3 (application: Wireless NAS). 3) Did the RasPi engineers take precautions against the generally well known [electromagnetic interferences between USB3 devices/cables and 2.4 Ghz WiFi networks](https://uk.pcmag.com/networking-3/13179/wireless-witch-the-truth-about-usb-30-and-wi-fi-interference), i.e. regarding PCB-design and plug-shielding?

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi 4 Model B uses the CYW43455 wireless chip, just like the Pi 3B+. The [specifications](https://www.cypress.com/documentation/datasheets/cyw43455-single-chip-5g-wifi-ieee-80211nac-macbaseband-radio-integrated) indicate that it provides single-stream 11ac. There are no visible ports for external antennas.

If you require something different, you could get a better USB wireless adapter (RTL8812AU-based, for example), but that might be cost prohibitive.

Comment: Can you clarify if channel width on the Pi is limited to 20Mhz or if the 40MHz/80Mhz are enabled? I couldn't tell from the data sheet and it may have been saying it was optional.